# Getting cumulative sum in specific column cells range. google sheets apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've create a function, but got an Error - Exception: You do not have permission to call setValue.

my code:

```
function cumulativeSum() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  
  if (currentCell) {
    var resultCellValue = currentCell.offset(0, 1).getValue() + currentCell.getValue();
    var resultCell = currentCell.offset(0, 1);
    resultCell.setValue(resultCellValue);
  }
}
```

I solved this error by creating a trigger, but now this function works for all cells.

And I need this function to work only for a specific range of column cells. For example B1:B20

What do you think?

Comment: From `Exception: You do not have permission to call setValue.`, how did you run your script? If you want to use your script as a custom function, such an error occurs because of the current specification of the custom function. But, if my guess was not correct, I apologize for this. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: I created a trigger for this function, but then I realized that this is not suitable, i.e. it always worked, in all cells

Comment: Better run this function on edit: function onEdit() { cumulativeSum(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function cumulativeSum() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const cc = sh.getCurrentCell();
  const a1 = cc.getA1Notation();
  const cs = Array.from(new Array(20).keys(),x => "B" + ( x + 1) );//["B1",..."B20]
  if(~cs.indexOf(a1)) {
    cc.offset(0, 1).setValue(cc.offset(0, 1).getValue() + cc.getValue());
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works well!
And I run this function on edit:

function onEdit() {
  cumulativeSum();
}